# Parse error when calling a static method on an object that's referenced by an instance property

Tags: php

Here's my test:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

class HasStatic {
  public static function static_method() {
    return true;
  }
}

class SUT {
  public $has_static;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->has_static = new HasStatic();
  }

  public function call_static() {
    // A parse error :<
    // $this->has_static::static_method();
    $has_static = $this->has_static;
    return $has_static::static_method();
  }

}

class PhpStaticCallOnProperty extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
  public function testPhpStaticCallOnProperty() {
    $sut = new SUT();
    $this->assertTrue($sut->call_static(), 'call_static() succeeded');
  }
}
```

As you can see, I discovered that `$this->has_static::static_method();` yields a parse error.

Is there a clean way to make this call without the extra assignment?

Comment: Can you try something like `($this->has_static)::static_method();` or `{$this->has_static}::static_method();`?

Comment: `HasStatic::static_method()` static method should call on a class.

Comment: @RocketHazmat these yield parse errors

Comment: @hallaji: Right, but, I don't have a reference to it as a symbol. I only have a reference to it as a property. Should I be using its name as a string? `$class = 'HasStatic'; $class::static_method()`?

Comment: I'm actually amazed even `$object_instance::static_method()` works... I've only ever seen `$classnameasastring::method()` or `LiteralClassName::method()`.

Comment: .. you really should avoid using static methods

Comment: @dimadima You can try this way: `call_user_func(array($classname, 'static_method'));` that returns the return value of the callback, or FALSE on error.

Comment: @tereško: What can someone make of a comment like "you should really avoid using static methods"? I'd love to know why you think that.

Comment: @Wrikken: yeah, I think _that_ is the problem. Not sure why I was doing that.

Comment: @dimadima because static code is inherently hard to test. It's procedural (and often tied to global state) programming in its very nature, that is just masked with OOP-like syntax. In case of static methods your class is simply acting as a namespace for those globally accessible functions.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @tereško! Now I can relate to that explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods are black boxes of functionality where you explicitly define everything going in (parameters) and out (return value). As such, they are not tied to an object - and you shouldn't call them using an object reference. `static_method()` should only ever be called using `HasStatic::static_method()`, or `self::static_method()` from within the `HasStatic` class.

There's nothing inherently wrong with static methods - I strongly disagree with tereško saying they should be avoided. If a method doesn't need an object's context, it may as well be static.

The parse error occurs because there's no reason to use the scope resolution operator (`::`) on a property. Variable class names do mean the following will work:

```
$foo = 'HasStatic';
$foo::static_method(); // equivalent to HasStatic::static_method()
```

However that variable cannot be a property - you'll have to assign it to a temporary variable if you want to call the method in this way.

Comment: Yeah you're right--I'm not sure why I was accessing the static member from an instance. I guess it does belong to the class. Low on sleep. Thank you.